# Qmail bounce using spamassassin

Tags: spamassassin, qmail

I have a qmail / spamd / clamd server and it’s recently started bouncing emails with a code 553. Spamhaus is sayings it’s an open relay problem on their message to the user. Has anyone come across this problem and how to configure it for qmail as the Spamhaus only has solutions for postfix/ others.

550 5.7.350 Remote server returned message detected as spam -> 553 Error: open resolver; https://www.spamhaus.org/returnc/pub/172.70.209.209

This is the message the user gets.

Comment: thibk about the configuration. as long you don't know how you do, consider not to host your own services. maybe mailciw would be a better option for you

Comment: It’s a system I inherited and at the moment that’s not an option

Answer (score 1):

Ended up removing the /usr/local/bin/rblsmtpd -b -rbl. line from the var/qmail/supervise/qmail-smtpd/run file